# ProgressDialog spinning circle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I want to implement ProgressDialog like this one, without additional frame.:
[image: Pic]

But I'm getting this one. How could I change that?

[image]

Here is my code for ProgressDialog:

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
   ............
   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
   mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
   mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
   ............
    public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Fragment,Void,Fragment>{
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }
            
            @Override
            protected Fragment doInBackground(Fragment... arg0) {   
                    //my stuff is here
            }
            
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Fragment result) {
                   mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can try this for creating custom dialogs
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26821095/1554031

Comment: This answer worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957263/why-the-background-of-progressdialog-doesnt-set-to-the-transparent

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Just change from `ProgressDialog` to `ProgressBar` in a layout:

**res/layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        //Your content here
     </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" >
        </ProgressBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**src/yourPackage/YourActivity.java**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{

private ProgressBar bar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    bar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    new ProgressTask().execute();
}
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {   
           //my stuff is here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
          bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}
```

**drawable/progress.xml** This is a custom `ProgressBar` that i use to change the default colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- 
    Duration = 1 means that one rotation will be done in 1 second. leave it.
    If you want to speed up the rotation, increase duration value. 
    in example 1080 shows three times faster revolution. 
    make the value multiply of 360, or the ring animates clunky 
-->
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/color_preloader_center"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="@color/color_preloader_end"
            android:startColor="@color/color_preloader_start"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Comment: thanks for answering.
What should I put to drawable folder? (what progress file is?)

Comment: what are the color code values for color_preloader_center, color_preloader_end and color_preloader_start?

Comment: @JackTurky can I use image drawable or animation to change that circle?

Comment: of course.. my progress.xml is an animation, you can change it as you want

Comment: @Sankar V the color are simple hex code, you can put whatever you want

Comment: Thx for this answer :) is there a way to make it rotate faster?

Comment: The rotation is not smooth in Gingerbread, Is there any way to optimize and make it smooth ?

Comment: It coverts in a black dark circle in Android Gingerbread after one spin. Can anybody knows why this is happening ?

Comment: @SankarV I used <color name="color_preloader_start">#000000</color>
    <color name="color_preloader_center">#000000</color>
    <color name="color_preloader_end">#ff56a9c7</color>

Comment: Where the image to put in drawable ?

Comment: @JaiminModi modi please check this post [how to create new android xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11714855/2584794)

Comment: I changed the value in the size tag for both height and width in the drawable/progress.xml, but it doesn't take any effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Dialogs have extra functionality over just a view - they are modal, and they can be set to not cancellable. If you want to lock the user until the task finishes, this answer won't be valid, as this does not imlement a modal solution

Answer (score 17):

Put this XML to show only the wheel:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:id="@+id/marker_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.VISIBLE` and the `ProgressBar` would slowly flash instead of constantly being visible, switched to `View.GONE` and `View.VISIBLE` and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

> ProgressBar Dialog - no need to all-time write custom progressBar code, create a below class and use

```
public class DProgressbar {
    Dialog progressDialog ;
    public DProgressbar(Context context) {
        progressDialog = new Dialog(context);
        progressDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_api_loading);
        progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    public void show(){
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    public void dismiss(){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

> R.layout.dialog_api_loading

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/size_10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="20dp">
<ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_20"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_20" />
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/txt_distance_5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Loading..." />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers provided.

Answer (score -7):

Try this.........

```
ProgressDialog pd1;
pd1=new ProgressDialog(<current context reference here>);
pd1.setMessage("Loading....");
pd1.setCancelable(false);
pd1.show();
```

To dismiss....

```
if(pd1!=null)
 pd1.dismiss();
```