# How Make ProgressDialog Centered and no Background?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I was able to display the dialog, but I can't make it centered and has no white background. How can I Make ProgressDialog Centered and no Background programmatically. Thanks^^

I got the idea from:
[ProgressDialog spinning circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585749/progressdialog-spinning-circle) , but I can't use this  xml.

```
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" >
        </ProgressBar>
```

+++++++++
This is inside  onPreExecute():

```
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main_Activity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress));
                pDialog.show();
```

**progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dip"
            android:width="48dip" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#00FFFF"
            android:centerY="0.50"
            android:endColor="#0000FF"
            android:startColor="#0000A0"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need dialog? Of course, it possible, but may be simply to add progress bar on your layout and show/hide it?