# Progress Dialog, use only a drawable

Tags: android, animation, progressdialog, android-drawable

I'm having trouble with the process dialog. 
I created a drawable that is 200 x 60 px and I created an animation for that drawable.

I want a dialog to pop up while loading... and I want this drawable to show up with an animation.

I tried this after searching on StackOverflow:

I created the animation:

../res/anim/progress_dialog_icon_drawable_animation.xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_2" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_3" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_4" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_5" android:duration="150" />
</animation-list>
```

And am calling:

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(Context.this);
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.anim.progress_dialog_icon_drawable_animation));
dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
dialog.show();
```

The image shows, but shrunk like the round progress 'circle' animation and I want it to be original size filling the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose from the question that you are using custom drawable, you can use a custom dialog with a custom view to set its content. Try  this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821095/1554031