# Custom ProgressDialog with Indeterminate Drawable not working

Tags: android

I have a Custom ProgressDialog with an custom drawable called on preexecute of an Async task as below

```
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BNMlogin.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

          progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating Credentials....");
          progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true); 
          progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_dialog_icon_drawable_animation));
          progressDialog.show();



                 }
```

The drawable is an animation list

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_1" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_2" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_3" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_4" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_5" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_6" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_7" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_8" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_9" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_10" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_11" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_progress_dialog_drawable_12" android:duration="150" />
```

Its crashing with the following error
......

```
11-27 15:30:43.439: E/AndroidRuntime(24834):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-27 15:30:43.439: E/AndroidRuntime(24834):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
11-27 15:30:43.439: E/AndroidRuntime(24834): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01006a a=-1}
11-27 15:30:43.439: E/AndroidRuntime(24834):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2063)
11-27 15:30:43.439: E/AndroidRuntime(24834):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
11-27 15:30:43.439: E/AndroidRuntime(24834):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
11-27 15:30:43.439: E/AndroidRuntime(24834):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3293)
```

Comment: You need to context to get the resources, so instead of this `getResources()` use `context.getResources()` or `BNMlogin.this.getResources()`

Comment: Still gives the same error on both instances

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are specifically using onpreexecute. If you want to create custom dialog you can refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821095/1554031

Answer (score -1):

try

```
    progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_dialog_icon_drawable_animation));
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.