# Custom ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, customization, progressdialog

I have a problem to change the color or something of progressDialog. I have seen many examples of change but did not meet my needs, I need your help  this is my code:

```
 @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS: 
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.download));
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mProgressDialog.setProgressDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.BLUE)); // my bad test
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                mProgressDialog.show();
                return mProgressDialog;
            default:
                return null;

        }

    }
```

Comment: To change the color or something?  What do you want to actually do?

Comment: change the yellow progress bar (default) with a drawable or if you can not with another color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onCreate` method of ProgressDialog and make any changes you want to its progress bar.

```
ProgressDialog mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this){
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Now we retrive this dialog ProgressBar
        ProgresBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
        //Do what you want with it here
    };
};
```

Comment: And that is exactly an answer to your question. ProgressDialog uses special layout file included in android to instantiate and setup view hierarchy containing ProgressBar, which in case show to you graphical strip representing progress of some action. If you want to change looks of progress bar in ProgressDialog you actually will change looks of ProgressBar used in ProgressDialog. Anything you do with ProgressBar in my example will be reflected on looks of ProgressDialog.

Comment: If you have some doubts, look at source code of ProgressDialog.

Comment: Sorry, this was typo. `findViewById` not `view.findViewById`

Comment: sorry my friend I replaced the variable "private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;" 

with your code and it give me NullPointerException

Comment: Mmm, you know, this is an example. You need to tweak it according your objects and code.

Comment: thanks friend I accepted your request I have only one question

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you can create custom progress dialog using Dialog class. 
You need to setcontentivew of dialog with your custom view.

Try this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26821095/1554031

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [the answer by @VallyN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815254/2171120) (who gave me the deciding help for this) and more recherche:

```
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
            bar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFF22C819 /*XXX FIXME getColor(R.color.colorAccent)*/, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            bar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFF22C819 /*XXX FIXME getColor(R.color.colorAccent)*/, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    };
```

This sets the progress bar colour to the desired value independent of whether it’s rendered as indeterminate or 0‥100 (the app in question uses both, first indeterminate until it’s known how much data to download).

The only thing I haven’t yet been able to figure out is how to actually get one of the colours from `colors.xml` to be used there, instead of the `0xAARRGGBB` notation. Edits welcome!