# Why the background of ProgressDialog doesn't set to the transparent?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-styles

I want to set the back ground to the transparent , so I have set the following code in

```
styles.xml
<style name="dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">  
            <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>  
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>  
            <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
            <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>  
            <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>  
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>  
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
        </style>
```

And I have use the `Progressdialog` like the following code in `JAVA file` and in `fragment`.

```
Activity activity = getActivity() ;
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity,R.style.dialog) ;
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false) ;
mProgressDialog.show() ;
```

But I get the progress like the following picture , and it doesn't has transparent background.

[image]

Why the background doesn't change to the transparent ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a progressDialog only with the spinner (in the middle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751662/create-a-progressdialog-only-with-the-spinner-in-the-middle)

Comment: **See also** [Dialog with transparent background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

create custom `MyTheme` in `values\styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

And also add this `CustomAlertDialogStyle` in `values\styles.xml`

```
 <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
<item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And set `ProgressDialog` like:

```
 pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(),R.style.MyTheme);
 pd.setCancelable(false);
 pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
 pd.show();
```

Comment: @Simple Plan , i'm sorry to bother you, but is there a way to change the progress widget via style ?

Comment: #M D, Is it possible to change its (progress bar) position with respect to other elements ? Currently its center align both vertically & horizontally.

Comment: @Mohit I am not trying this but you can set Gravity in your style .

Comment: Tried but no success ! Apart from this, nice solution.

Comment: Thanks. Also you may add to a style a following line: <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Large</item> in order to make it large.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this code,work fine in devices >= 19 (Kitkat)

```
progress = ProgressDialog.show(Splash.this, null, null, true);
            progress.setContentView(R.layout.elemento_progress_splash);
            progress.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

            //progress.show();
```

[image]

Comment: If you do ProgressDialog.show(), you do not need to call progress.show(). Otherwise, this answer works fine.

Comment: If you do ProgressDialog.show(Splash.this, null, null, true) you do not have to do progress.show(). Otherwise this solution works well.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
mProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

EDIT:

Try adding this to the layout xml

```
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: Sorry...it is the same. But the another answer is working. Also thank for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this. It's working for me.

In `styles.xml`

```
<style name="TransparentProgressDialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

  </style>
```

In `Activity/Fragment`:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.TransparentProgressDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just define at **color.xml** the variables

For light style:
`<color name="accent_material_light">#000000</color>`

For dark style:
`<color name="accent_material_dark">#000000</color>`

These changes affect the whole system