# How to remove this png image's white background?

Tags: android, image, image-processing

I have a png image , when I run my android application then the white background of the image is shown ! How to make the image's background transparent ? Here is the captured photo :
[image]

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957263/why-the-background-of-progressdialog-doesnt-set-to-the-transparent/21957406#21957406](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957263/why-the-background-of-progressdialog-doesnt-set-to-the-transparent/21957406#21957406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *Photoshop*. Use the *magic wand* to choose the white pixels, then use *del* key on the keyboard. After that, save it and re import it to the project.