# How to make ProgressDialog Transparent in android

Tags: android

I want to make ProgressDialog Transparent but I never became Transparent It became Black background in ProgressDialog.How can I do that Kindly help

here is my code for ProgressDialog:-

```
private class LoginAttempt extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyTheme);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        pDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        pDialog.show();

    }
```

here is my style.xml

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

and also

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and here is my result:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvVP5.png)

Comment: make sure you give <color name="transparent">#00000000</color> in colors.xml

Comment: @Rooban : no need of that. Color.Transparent supplies the required value

Comment: Check below Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957263/why-the-background-of-progressdialog-doesnt-set-to-the-transparent/21957406

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (Assuming I am in MainActivity) :

```
    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
    pDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    pDialog.show();
```

OR, if I just do

```
 ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

i.e. without supplying any theme, it works.

So turns out there's a problem in the theme that you are supplying. Try once without supplying the theme.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It still show white dialog with indicator at the left.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking  `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>` you have to define `color` in your `color.xml` for full transparency. like this:

```
<color name="transparent">#00FFFFFF</color>
```

Look here for reference:[Transparent ARGB hex value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201134/transparent-argb-hex-value)

Comment: but I dont want black color

Comment: I dont want any color at background I want only transparent instead of black

Comment: @Raj thats why i said you change the hex value of transparent color. U can check the link for the reason why are you getting little black transparent color.

Comment: by changing color still have same problem

Answer (score 0):

First, define your object:

```
    private static ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
```

Then create the method to run your progress dialog that includes the transparent background as below:

```
    public static void showSimpleProgressDialog(Context context, String title, String msg, boolean isCancelable) {
    try {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, msg);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);
            mProgressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        }
        if (!mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        re.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can then call this method from your activity as:

```
showSimpleProgressDialog(this, "Your Title", "Your Message", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in style file

```
    <style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateTint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

and this for calling progress dialog :

```
       ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context,R.style.MyTheme);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    progressDialog.setMessage("");
    progressDialog.show();
```